# Problems with firebase authentication in vue3

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

I want to make a form that will do authentication with the help of firebase 9. Project is made with Vue3. I have an HTML form:

```
<form @submit.prevent="registr">
        <div class="inputs">
          <div class="input user">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" v-model="username">
          </div>
          <div class="input email">
            <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" v-model="email">
          </div>
          <div class="input password">
            <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" v-model="password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit"> Sign In </button>
      </form>
```

imports:

```
import 'animate.css';
import "firebase/auth"
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
```

and data & methods in script part:

```
    data() {
    return{
      username: null,
      email: null,
      password: null,
    }
  },
methods: {
    register(){
      console.log('WORK');
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
              .then(() => {
                console.log('success')
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.error(err)
              })
    }
  }
```

Though, any part of the methods is not working, even simple console.log, which I add to see if form connects with function in the right way. Also, i have an error in console: `Uncaught TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.default is undefined`. Why method is not working with the form?

To initialize firebase i used following code:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "#################################",
  authDomain: "decbase-#####.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "decbase-#####",
  storageBucket: "decbase-#####.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "############",
  appId: "1:0000000000:web:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebaseApp;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is defined/imported, and how you initialize Firebase?

Comment: sure, i edited question with imports and initialization of firebase

Comment: That last code block seems to use an older version of the SDK. Are you sure you're *only* including v9?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, there are mistakes in initialization, i fixed it due to current documentation. Though the situation didn't change, and console error changed to vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default is undefined

Answer (score 0):

in the initialization:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "############################################",
  authDomain: "#####-#####.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "#####-#####",
  storageBucket: "#####-#####.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "############",
  appId: "1:00000000000:web:######################"
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default getAuth(firebaseApp);
```

methods& imports in the component:

```
import "firebase/auth"
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
methods: {
    async register(){
      console.log("WORK");
      const auth = getAuth();
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.email, this.password)
              .then(() => {
                console.log("success")
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.error(err)
              })

    }
```

and in the HTML part in button tag should be added @click:

```
<button type="submit" @click="register"> Sign In </button>
```